# Can't see certain files on Android phone in Ubuntu

Tags: android

I can see my Android phone on the Ubuntu (16.04) laptop, and can see most of the files. But certain random files I just can't see, even though I can see other files in the same folder. 
I have had this problem in the past with different Android phones and earlier versions of Android (I'm currently using Lineage 14.1 / Android 7.1.2) and worked around it by using a file manager on the phone to copy the files to a different location. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. There seems to be no pattern at all. 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I think I've had this same issue. I'll check once I'm home.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I've had this problem before too, not just on Ubuntu, but on Windows as well. I think there's a bug in Android's implementation of MTP.

**Edit:** [Yup, this has been a known bug in Android since October 2012](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282)

Essentially, if you create a file on the phone without rebooting, the computer doesn't see it even though you can pull it with ADB just fine.

So I think the answer is to just reboot the phone or use `adb pull`.

Comment: It worked ! I was just too lazy to use adb.